# Render page within winforms with one of the installed browsers?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, browser

I wanted to make my own "editor" to for html, css, etc, where on one side I have the code and on the other how it looks like on the browser.

I know within c# we have the handy `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser()` that could do that for me but I wanted to be able to make it render as if it was using ie or ff or chrome browsers.

- **How could I render the page some how as if it was using one of
  those (considering they are installed and available within the
  computer but to open on the c# winforms) ?**

Comment: I think there are libs for FF and Webkit you can use to do this. (Well, Webkit *is* a library... but you get my idea)... Incidentally, for your purposes, I would also look at seeing if you can get the IE to render as IE7 or 8, assuming it is 9 you have installed.

Comment: @AndrewBarber that's exactly what I am looking for, I want to be able to render the browser as well as being able to pick which version I want it to render as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use the rendering engine that the other browsers use. For example, Chrome and Safari use [Webkit](http://www.webkit.org/). Getting this to work for older browsers like IE6, 7, will be much harder, since they don't release their layout engine. IE9 has a feature that lets you render a page as an older browser, but I'm not sure if you can use that feature using the WebBrowser control.

Comment: I would forget IE6, but IE9's tools allow you to render pages as if it were IE7 or IE8, so I wonder if it's possible to do the same via the WebBrowser control, somehow.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I just edited my post to mention that as you commented. :P